# Jquery ajax exposes php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following code

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:"processes/get_user_menu.php",
    success: function(output) {
        $("#likes").html(output);
    }
});
```

I want to know if there is another way to do this so that the php file location is not exposed?

Comment: What concerns you about revealing the location of the script? You can enforce measures against direct access, which is much better than trying to hide the file.

Comment: I am using php's $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']. Is this secure enough?

Comment: Whats wrong if the user see's your file?

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely *nothing* you can do to stop from exposing the requested php file.  Any browser of any kind has the ability to record ajax request URLs, so a user can easily see what URL is being requested.  Additionally, there is nothing to prevent any user agent from setting the `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` header to whatever it wants.  Don't be prepared to expose a URL to the client side unless you can do so without restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you use, you can hide your `.php` extension and use folder-style of address, with or without ending slash, but that's about it.
[Read this on **php.net**](http://php.net/manual/en/security.hiding.php) (or use your frameworks utilities, if you're using a framework)

Comment: And try accepting some answers if you want people to be interested in helping you.
Just sayin